# Ionic trigger modal open function with ion-searchbar focus - click not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an `ion-searchbar` that, when clicked, opens a modal. However, currently the `click` process is actually taking two clicks, one to focus, one to open the modal. I have tried to add the click to the `ion-toolbar` it is contained in, and have tried to disable the `ion-searchbar` with `[disabled]="true"`, but the disabled functionality isn't available to the `ion-searchbar`. How can I trigger the new modal to open without having to double click, and in such a way that the focus doesn't happen on the original searchbar?

**HTML**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar >
    <ion-searchbar (click)="openSearchModal()"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

**JS**

```
  openSearchModal() {
    let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(SearchmodalPage); 
    myModal.present(); 
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `<ion-searchbar (tap)=` instead of `(click)` ?

Comment: @maudulus Could you provide some feedback on the provided answers so that we can possibly adjust and help you better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you are saying, `ion-searchbar` doesn't have a disabled functionnality.

But you can create your own searchbar, that will use ionic classes to avoid recoding it and you will be able to disable it.

See my code here :

```
<ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar>
    <div class="searchbar searchbar-ios searchbar-left-aligned searchbar-active" (click)="openSearchModal()">
      <div class="searchbar-input-container">
        <div class="searchbar-search-icon"></div>
        <input class="searchbar-input" placeholder="Search" type="search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" disabled="true">
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this function inside the class of your .ts file (best practice is before constructor):

```js
ionViewDidLoad(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('searchbar-input')[0].setAttribute("onFocus", "openSearchModal()");
}
```

### Explanation

The `ion-searchbar` ionic element creates multiple child elements, one of which is of course an `input` element which has a class `searchbarElement`.

We first ask to get all those elements with this class name. This returns an array of such elements, in the first position of which, at index = 0, resides the `<input>` field of which the functionality we want to change.

We then programmatically set an [`onFocus` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus) that is called when an element gains focus (e.g. when clicked). This in essence makes it look like the following:

```
<input class="searchbar-input" onFocus="openSearchModal()">
```

So in the end, when the user clicks on the search box, the modal is called.

We then wrap all of this inside an `ionViewDidLoad()` which is [a lifecycle hook ionic provides](http://blog.ionic.io/navigating-lifecycle-events/) that we can use to run code right after the view has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable child component of the .
In fact, this ionic tag is working with input dom.
So if you set disable attribute to 'true'  will be disabled.

**HTML**

```
<ion-searchbar id="searchBar"></ion-searchbar>
```

**ts**

```
let ionSearchBarInputBox = document.getElementById("searchBar").getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
ionSearchBarInputBox[0].disabled=true;
```